# How do I work around mutability in moment.js?

Tags: javascript, object, immutability, momentjs, mutability

I've run into a problem where I have to store the initial values of a moment object but I'm having some trouble preventing my variable from changing along with the original object.

Unfortunately `Object.freeze()` doesn't work, because moment.js returns an `Invalid date` error when I try to format that.

Comment: And the code looks like…? If you want to store the initial value, store the time value, available using the *valueOf* method or implicit conversion to number.

Comment: once your variable is set, it is set, it wont change automagically, so rather look to not set it again and again

Answer (score 218, accepted):

There's a Moment.js plugin on NPM called [frozen-moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/frozen-moment) - You could use `moment().freeze()` in place of `Object.freeze(moment())`.

Otherwise, vanilla Moment.js has a `clone` method that should help you avoid mutability problems, so you could do something like this:

```
var a = moment(),
    b = a.clone(); // or moment(a)
```

**UPDATE:**

It has been two years since I wrote this answer. In this time, another library for working with dates has surfaced and gained a lot of traction: https://date-fns.org/

This library is immutable by default and follows a modular, functional architecture, which means it is better suited to tree shaking and client-side bundling. If you are working on a project that makes extensive use of Webpack on the client side, and find that Moment.js is giving you trouble with your build, or even if Moment.js' mutability is causing you a lot of headache, then you should give `date-fns` a try.

Comment: Well, I'm using moment.js in the fullCalendar plugin and it turns out I was getting the moment object data from a later state of my event than I was supposed to. Mutability issues are definitely a thing with moment.js though, so thank you very much for the suggestion and sorry I wasted your time.

Comment: You can manipulate stored `moment` variable without mutating it: just use clone() like this:
`zz = moment();
zz.clone().add(3, 'h').toISOString();`

Comment: Note that date-fns has very poor timezone support and no support for UTC dates.

Comment: I've been using `date-fns` for a while now but have since had to jump into legacy code using Moment and boy, did this post save me from jumping out of a window.

Comment: [`dayjs`](https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs) is also a good alternative since it has APIs similar to Moment.js with immutable nature. (As of March 2019, it lacks timezone support but this is a fairly new library and I can observe that the work is ongoing.)

Answer (score 4):

It's an old question and apologies for shameless self promotion as this is not my intention, just hope it will help someone.

In addition to what razorbeard says (`.clone()` etc) I created NPM module that attaches immutable methods to whatever Moment.js comes with out of the box. The intention is not to break existing code so module adds new methods with `Immu` appended to its name.

Each instance returned by moment factory will be decorated with immutable methods e.g `moment().startOf()` will have corresponding `startOfImmu()`, `add()` will have `addImmu()` etc. Each of those returns new moment rather then modifying existing one. To use it just pass `moment` factory to `momentImmutableMethods` to get access to new immutable methods.  Example:

```
var moment = require('moment'); // or moment-timezone 
import { momentImmutableMethods } from 'moment-immutable-methods';

// to decorate instances with immutable methods we need to extend moment factory as below:
momentImmutableMethods(moment);

// now every instance returned by moment will have Immu methods attached.


// IMMUTABLE EXAMPLE
// we using immutable methods that were attached to every instance, these have Immu appended to original name
const ddd = moment({
  hour: 5,
  minute: 10
});
// Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: {…}, _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, _locale: Locale, …}
const eee = ddd.startOfImmu('day');
// Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: {…}, _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, _locale: Locale, …}
console.log(ddd === eee);
// false
const fff = eee.startOfImmu('month');
// Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: {…}, _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, _locale: Locale, …}
console.log(ddd === fff);
// false
console.log(eee === fff);
// false
console.log(ddd.format('DD/MM/YY HH:mma'));
// "14/04/18 05:10am"
console.log(eee.format('DD/MM/YY HH:mma'));
// "14/04/18 00:00am"
console.log(fff.format('DD/MM/YY HH:mma'));
// "08/04/18 00:00am"
```

Its on NPM at https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-immutable-methods

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [day.js](https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs) library which has almost the exact API of moment.js but is immutable.