# Replacing an object without losing reactivity with Vue 3 (composition API)

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I would like to update my object and keep the reactivity. `selectedTime` is a Date object, `substractMonths` will return a new Date object.

```html
<span
   class="calendar__pickable__chevron"
   @click="selectedTime = substractMonths(1, selectedTime)"
   >
   <span>
      <font-awesome-icon icon="chevron-left" />
   </span>
</span>
```

The problem is that by doing this, my state is not updated because Vue 3 is not able to detect the replacement of the object.

How I can fix this it ? (I specify that I have used `const selectedTime = ref(new Date())` to create a reactive object).

[image]

Substract function does return new `Date` object.

Part of code: https://gist.github.com/SirMishaa/efb0efe74c6355aabbcb853f7650c22f

The only thing I try to do is to execute a function that returns a new date, and replace my `selectedTime` with **the return value of the function.**

Comment: Are you aware of [computed properties](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/computed.html)? Did you try to extract `substractMonths(1, selectedTime)` into a computed?

Comment: I'm using the [composition API](https://composition-api.vuejs.org/), how this is working with it ?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Why you need it ? I'm only taking a date, I add the selected number of months and I return the new Date.

Comment: I don't think I need a computed method, I'm just trying to mutate my state. I make a datepicker, for context.

Comment: This is not reproducible

Comment: @Dan, this is simple. Make a component, use an object and mute it using a function. And you will see the error. This is kinda simple.

Comment: Have a look at the [site guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to understand the meaning of a good question with reproducible error.  And also notice:  `DO NOT use images of code.`

Comment: The image is just to represent the type of return functions and they are not useful in solving my problem. I still know that images are not practical. I'm going to make a reply with a new simple code to show my problem.

Comment: @Dan Thanks you for your jsfiddle, Indeed, this is working good. My code is here, and I'm on this error since 2 days : https://github.com/SirMishaa/vue-datepicker/blob/master/src/components/DatePicker.vue sorry If i'm a bit salty. I can't get why this isn't working.

Comment: A good next step would be replacing `substractMonths(1, selectedTime)` with `new Date()` and reporting the results.

Comment: @Misha The might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40959483/why-does-vue-js-not-update-the-dom-with-datepicker-using-moment-js. Your date functions modify the original date and return it. Since the reference to `selectedTime` hasn't changed, Vue doesn't detect it, so the template doesn't update. One workaround is for your date functions to create a new date from the original (which I think you might've intended to begin with). https://codesandbox.io/s/updating-date-object-in-template-9nmlj?file=/src/utils/date-utils.js:203-239

Comment: I've made a codesanbox with a small example, this is kinda boring... : https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-paper-o952k?file=/src/App.vue
Thank you for your answer, I'll try it.

Comment: @tony19 Indeed, this is wokring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have finally solved the problem, so I will describe the solution.

I created a small example : https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-paper-o952k?file=/src/App.vue

```html
<template>
  <h1>{{ currentTime.toString() }}</h1>
  <button @click="currentTime = addMonths(1, currentTime)">
    Add one month
  </button>
</template>
```

```js
function addMonths(numberOfMonths, currentTime) {
  const x = currentTime.getDate();
  currentTime.setMonth(currentTime.getMonth() + numberOfMonths);
  console.log(`Function has been called with : ${currentTime}`);
  if (currentTime.getDate() !== x) {
    currentTime.setDate(0);
  }
  return currentTime;
}
```

Vue is unable to detect the change because I return an object that has the same reference (as the old object). The s**olution is therefore to create a new object**, in order to allow the change to be detected.

Insead of `return currentTime;`, do something like this `return new Date(currentTime)` will work.

I'm glad If I could help. I've been looking for the solution for a long time