# min/max and start/end don't work together

Tags: javascript, vis.js, vis.js-timeline

The options for my [Vis](http://visjs.org/docs/timeline/) timeline are as follows...

```
var options = {

    height: '150px',
    min: start.add(-3, 'M'),
    max: finish.add(3, 'M'),
    start: start,
    end: finish,
    zoomMin: 21600000
};
```

I'm finding that with this config, start and finish are ignored and the initial visible period is bounded by min and max.

If I remove min and max, then the initial visible period is start and end, except that the min and max are thousands of years in the past and future.

How do I use both of these sets of properties at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vis is not the problem here but `moment.js`.
The documentation for the [`add`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) method says:

> **Mutates** the **original** moment by adding time.

So the adding is made in place and basically when you call it to set `min` and `max`, this also does it for the `start` and `end`.

To solve this, you can either initialize two objects when you create your `start` and `finish` object or you can go with some other workaround like is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30979178/how-do-i-work-around-mutability-in-moment-js).

Comment: I've tried using `clone()` like this... `start.clone().add(-3, 'M')` but it's having no effect.

Comment: Try making it outside your options object and assign it to variables. Then print to see what dates it is getting. If you make a fiddle I can help you with that.

Comment: Instead of adding a negative value, consider using substract: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/